# xdt:transform with similar attributes

Tags: xdt-transform

I have a configuration file that contains WCF settings:

```
<host>
    <add baseAddress="net.tcp://myaddress.com:12345/MyService"/>
    <add baseAddress="net.tcp://anotheraddress:67890/MyOtherService"/>
</host>
```

The 'add' element only has a baseAddress attribute and so I can't use the Match locator. How would one approach transforming multiple elements like in my example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I ended up doing was moving the xdt:Transform="Replace" to the parent node like:

```
<host xdt:Transform="Replace">
    <add baseAddress="net.tcp://myaddress.com:12345/MyService"/>
    <add baseAddress="net.tcp://anotheraddress:67890/MyOtherService"/>
</host>
```